# Bigquery parameterized subqueries

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large query that I'd like to parameterized to make it neater.

Currently I have;

```
select * from (select x,y,z from table_1 where z > 1) table_one
left join (select x,y,z from table_2 where z > 1) table_two on table_1.x = table_2.x
```

Is it possible to do something like;

```
var first = (select x,y,z from table_1 where z > 1) 
var second = (select x,y,z from table_2 where z > 1) 

select * from first
left join second on first.x = second.x
```

Comment: there are too many options to write same thing in a different ways. your example is not an exception here! Can you please provide some context of your use case, so we can help targeting your specific needs. Meantime - using CTE is the most common way as Yun Zhang has already mentioned, while using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` here makes absolutely no sense at all to me - but I can be wrong as I don't really know your actual use case

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: If you look into the question, there are couple of things clearly mentioned: [1] Parameterized and [2] Variables also used as expectations. Those 2 things drive to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax wise, `WITH` clause or temp table may be something that you are looking for

```sql
WITH first AS (select x,y,z from table_1 where z > 1) ,
     second AS (select x,y,z from table_2 where z > 1) 
select * from first
left join second on first.x = second.x
```

Most of the time, using temp table leads to less optimization and higher cost because it is materializing data which could have been excluded in a full query. TEMP table is still a powerful feature and could be useful, so still post it here:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE first AS select x,y,z from table_1 where z > 1;
CREATE TEMP TABLE second AS select x,y,z from table_2 where z > 1;

select * from first
left join second on first.x = second.x
```

Comment: Thanks, the with aspect is what I was looking for. I ended up finding the docs here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause